# Android Bitmap/Canvas offset after scale

Tags: java, android, graphics, android-canvas

If I have a canvas, on which I draw a Bitmap like this:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bmLargeImage, srcRect, destRect, paint);
```

and I scale the bitmap:

```
canvas.scale(1.5f, 1.5f, 450, 250);
```

I want to get the position of the Bitmap after the scale. If the position before scale was (0, 0), after scale there is a offset and I need that offset.. how can I get it?

Thanks and sorry for the simple question, newbie here...

Comment: You have to calculate it, here is a hint: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6749723/android-get-bitmap-rect-left-top-right-bottom-on-a-canvas/6750631#6750631

Comment: so If I have objectOldX = 0, and pivotX is 360, and scaleX is 1.3, then the new object would be 0 + (0 - 360)*1.3, which gives -468 .. hm .. will check now.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ok lets try to work out the best formula for this

```
canvas.scale(scaleX, scaleY, pivotX, pivotY);  

if (scaleX >= 1){    
  objectNewX = objectOldX + (objectOldX - pivotX)*(scaleX - 1); 
}else{   
  objectNewX = objectOldX - (objectOldX - pivotX)*(1 - scaleX); 
}
```

The same for objectNewY. The new width and height of the bitmap would of course be the multiple of the old size and scale.

Comment: this is awesome man! can you gimme example on how to do it for other corners :( I am newbie I know, and I lack math knowledge :( thanks a lot man!

Comment: There are two ways. One is to use the same formula for the opposite corner and another is to calculate the new size and add it to the new coordinates of top-left position which resulted from the code above.

Comment: I can't vote you up since I am new, otherwise would give you all the karma in the world. :) thanks.

Comment: is there any example for other corners...:( m unable to handle them...plz

Comment: I was going to post my question regarding canvas restriction but I found your formula. How can I thank?? :).You really helped me.
You thank you,thank you,thank you,thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the cleanest Solution would be to use the underlying transformation Matrix of the Canvas you are manipulating.

In Android there is the `canvas.getMatrix(Matrix cmt)` method available which will yield it. The transformation matrix will transform any point in world space you throw at into screen coordinates. Just use the `matrix.mapPoints(float[] points)` and you will be fine.

FYI, you can easily do it the other way around too. If you want to know what screen coordinate maps to which point in world space, e.g. for tapping; the inverse matrix can be used for that. It can be obtained via the `matrix.invert(Matrix out)` method. Use its `mapPoints()` for the coordinate mapping then.

Here are the official docs:
[mapPoints()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html#mapPoints%28float%5B%5D%29), [invert()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html#invert%28android.graphics.Matrix%29), [getMatrix()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#getMatrix%28%29)

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like know the corners of your screen relative to your original canvas, you can use `canvas.getClipBounds()`. This returns a `Rect` with edge coordinates relative to your original canvas. For instance, if you start off with a canvas size of 320 x 480 and call

```
canvas.scale(2, 2, getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2);
```

and then

```
canvas.getClipBounds();
```

you will have a `Rect` (call this `rect`) where

```
rect.top == 120
rect.bottom == 360
rect.left == 80
rect.right == 240
```