# can we zoom in zoom out the drawing we draw on the Canvas android

Tags: android

I am trying to make an application in which i can zoom in and draw some thing on the image 
i have used following link to make a zoomable image view which is working fine
[zoom functionality for images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537238/how-can-i-get-zoom-functionality-for-images)

now the problem is that i dont know how to scale and translate  whatever i am drawing on my canvas  to the image size when it is zoomed out. 
following is the onDraw() function.
i have recorded the touch points added them into a list and  in this onDraw() function of my view i am retrieving those points but these points are relative to screen .
i have to translate and scale it according to the image operation(in case of zoom in/out of the image) .

```
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
super.onDraw(canvas);

if(mMarkers!=null)
{
for(Marker m : mMarkers) {
    // draw the marker
     Log.v("IP","position"+ m.x+"    "+ m.y);
    Paint paint=new Paint();
    paint.setARGB(255, 2, 255, 2);
    canvas.drawText("O", m.x, m.y, paint);

    if(x!=-1){
         Log.v("IP","LINE"+x+"   " + y+ "  "+ m.x+"    "+ m.y);
    canvas.drawLine(x, y,m.x, m.y, paint);
    }
    x=m.x;
    y=m.y;
}
x=y=-1;
```

}

}

Comment: Hey take a look at the following SO question of mine.. this will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7524843/get-canvas-coordinates-after-scaling-up-down-or-dragging-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent env) {
float x = env.getX() / mScaleFactor + rect.left;
float y = env.getY() / mScaleFactor + rect.top;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent env) {
float x = env.getX() / mScaleFactor + rect.left;
float y = env.getY() / mScaleFactor + rect.top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get 9 point array from the matrix which contain the relative x,y and scale factor  in x and y use this to convert you current `x,y` (which is with respect to screen) to x,y on original image and reconvert it before drawing again on different zoom levels.